# Run all possible combinations of a range of values in C#

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I have a Parameter Class with properties for a range of different values (from Min to Max)

```
class Parameter
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a list of Parameters, for example :

```
    var Params = new List<Parameter>();
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 7, Max = 12, Value = 9 });
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 18, Max = 24, Value = 21 });
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 49, Max = 60, Value = 54 });
```

My problem is I need to run some code with all possible combinations of each parameter values (e.g. setting parameter 1's Value to 7, 8, ... to 12).

I also need the code to work for an undefined number of Parameters in the list (in this example there are only 3, but there could be more). Obviously the amount of work is going to increase exponentially with the number of parameters in the list

I'm assuming I'm going to need some kind of recursive function. Anyone got any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: I believe this is called a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: I find this part of your question needs clarification:
"My problem is I need to run some code with all possible combinations of each parameter values (e.g. setting parameter 1's Value to 7, 8, ... to 12)."

Comment: Eric Lippert has some articles on his blog that cover this type of exercise you might want to look at https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Comment: You can translate your ranges into a collection of all the values with `Enumerable.Range(Min, Max - Min + 1)`

Comment: @Scott Actually I think the OP wants a Cartesian product, but it's somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
public static void IterateParams(Parameter[] parameters, int depth = 0)
{
    // If we had iterated each parameter
    if (depth == parameters.Length)
    {
        // Then do something with values, for example print it
        int[] values = parameters.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values));
    }
    else // Else iterate through the values of the next parameter
    {
        var parameter = parameters[depth];

        for (int i = parameter.Min; i <= parameter.Max; i++)
        {
            parameter.Value = i;
            IterateParams(parameters, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var Params = new List<Parameter>();
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 7, Max = 12, Value = 9 });
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 18, Max = 24, Value = 21 });
    Params.Add(new Parameter { Min = 49, Max = 60, Value = 54 });

    IterateParams(Params.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Yes - from the output that looks like it does the job. I thought some kind of recursion would do it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you couldn't do a simple foreach loop?

```
foreach (Parameter param in Params)
{
   DoCalculation(param)
}
```

Then your function would look something like this with a for loop

```
public void DoCalculation (Parameter param)
{
   for (int i = param.Min; i <= param.Max; i++)
   {
      param.Value = i;
      //Do Calculation necessary
   }
}
```

Comment: I code be wrong, but I think the OP wants the combination of all parameters so {7, 18, 49}, {8, 18, 49}, ... {12, 18, 49 }, {7, 19, 49} and so on up to the max of all three {12, 24, 60}

Comment: That would just run through each value - I need it to run through each combination of values

Answer (score 0):

You have list of params so start with that
Loop through that using foreach here is the algorithm

```
For each parameter
    start from min and increment by one untill you reach max
         assign to value to perform function 
         (code or function to run with value as param here)
    finish this loop (it can be while or for loop)
finish this loop (for each loop in c# would do)
```

Try this and let us know. From your question its not clear what you have tried so far. My answer is based on what you have provided so far.